# Can we force the mainWindow to focus on some DOM after restore from minimize in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am writing a desktop version for google translate with Electron. And I hope that every time the app restores from minimization, the textArea can be focused. Therefore, I tried

```
mainWindow.on('restore',() => {
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
        document.getElementById('source-is').focus();
    `);
});
```

Where 'source-is' is the id for the textArea. But it does not work. The focus is kept on < body />. Can someone help me with it? My platform is win10. Thank you!

Comment: I generally use the pattern mainWindow.webContents.send('focus-event',{}) to send a message to the window and then in the renderer process I handle that event to focus. i.e. in the renderer process event handler I use 'document.getElementById('source-is').focus() and this seems to work for me. Maybe you could try that?

Comment: "The focus is kept on < body />" how do you test that?

Comment: By print the focus using DevTool.